# Why does xmlLinq attribute kill XSL transform?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an XSLT that iterates over this XML and selects elements from the "InterestingData" node.

The transform is failing because of this attribute that's in the "DontNeed2" node: `xmlns:xmlLinq="clr-namespace:System.Xml.Linq;assembly=System.Xml"`

So if I completely remove that attribute, the transform succeeds. However, I don't control the generation of that XML so I need to be able to handle it.
How can this attribute that's in a node that the XSL doesn't even select have the ability to kill the transform, and how do I work around that?

SomeTech.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Root xmlns="">
  <DontNeed1>
    <Item name="one" />
    <Item name="two" />
    <Item name="three" />
  </DontNeed1>
  <DontNeed2>
    <transporters:SomeWebServiceTransportActivity xmlns:transporters="clr-namespace:SomeTech.DataFeed.Activities.Transporters;assembly=SomeTech.DataFeed" xmlns:out="clr-namespace:SomeTech.DataFeed;assembly=SomeTech.DataFeed" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:compModel="clr-namespace:SomeTech.DataFeed.ComponentModel;assembly=SomeTech.DataFeed" xmlns:channel="clr-namespace:SomeTech.DataFeed.Engine.Channel;assembly=SomeTech.DataFeed" xmlns:engine="clr-namespace:SomeTech.DataFeed.Engine;assembly=SomeTech.DataFeed" xmlns:kernel="clr-namespace:SomeTech.Kernel.Channel;assembly=SomeTech.Kernel" xmlns="clr-namespace:SomeTech.DataFeed;assembly=SomeTech.DataFeed" xmlns:schema="clr-namespace:System.Xml.Schema;assembly=System.Xml" xmlns:xmlLinq="clr-namespace:System.Xml.Linq;assembly=System.Xml" xmlns:domain="clr-namespace:SomeTech.Common.Domain;assembly=SomeTech.Common" xmlns:s="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib" x:Key="transportActivity" SearchType="ReportId" RecordsPerFile="100" UseWindowsAuth="false" IsWindowsAuthSpecific="false" TempFileOnErrorAction="DoNothing" TempFileOnErrorRenameString="">
    </transporters:SomeWebServiceTransportActivity>
  </DontNeed2>
  <InterestingData>
    <Items>
      <Item>Apple</Item>
    </Items>
    <Items>
      <Item>Orange</Item>
    </Items>
  </InterestingData>
</Root>
```

SomeTech.xsl

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <body>
        <table border="1">
          <tr bgcolor="#cccccc">
            <th style="text-align:left">Item</th>
          </tr>
          <xsl:for-each select="Root/InterestingData/Items">
            <tr>
              <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="Item"/>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </table>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

SomeTech.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Demo XSLT</title>
    <script>
        function loadXMLDoc(filename) {
            if (window.ActiveXObject) {
                xhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
            }
            else {
                xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            }
            xhttp.open("GET", filename, false);
            try { xhttp.responseType = "msxml-document" } catch (err) { } // Helping IE11
            xhttp.send("");
            return xhttp.responseXML;
        }


        function displayResult() {
            xml = loadXMLDoc("SomeTech.xml");
            xsl = loadXMLDoc("SomeTech.xsl");

            // code for IE
            if (window.ActiveXObject || xhttp.responseType == "msxml-document") {
                ex = xml.transformNode(xsl);
                document.getElementById("example").innerHTML = ex;
            }
                // code for Chrome, Firefox, Opera, etc.
            else if (document.implementation && document.implementation.createDocument) {
                xsltProcessor = new XSLTProcessor();
                xsltProcessor.importStylesheet(xsl);
                resultDocument = xsltProcessor.transformToFragment(xml, document);
                document.getElementById("example").appendChild(resultDocument);
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="displayResult()">
    <div id="example" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please post enough code (XML+XSLT) to enable us reproduce the issue.

Comment: Added code for reproducing issue. FYI This is using VS 2013, Windows 7, IE 9.

Comment: I don't see any problem with your XSLT code.

Comment: Have you tried loading not doing the transform yet still loading the XSL doc to see if the issue may be on the loading rather than the transform itself?

Comment: JB King: Yes, the XSL document does load successfully even when the transform fails. (I exaimed the contents.)

Comment: I've discovered that the issue does not occur with Chrome but does occur with IE. (This box only has IE9, so I don't know whether the transform works correctly with newer IE versions.) Why would IE fail to transform when this attribute is present in a node that isn't even being transformed? xmlns:xmlLinq="clr-namespace:System.Xml.Linq;assembly=System.Xml"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be an issue/bug only in IE9.